# "device unauthorized" при подключении телефона в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, устройство

Купил новый смартфон (Samsung Galaxy S4 mini). Подключаю и вижу в Android Studio: `"device unauthorized..."`

Comment: Оформите вашу справку в виде вопроса (оставьте только часть до многоточия), затем дайте на него свой ответ (остальная часть)  и отметьте его как верный. Помимо правильного оформления это нехитрое действие немного прибавит вам рейтинга :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В англоязычной версии есть вариант [решения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081263/adb-android-device-unauthorized) , но мне оно не помогло.
Оказалось всё гораздо проще. В параметрах разработчика нужно отключить проверку приложения на нежелательные действия.

Comment: Я понимаю, но лучше лишний раз напомнить.